# Dynamic columned HTML page layout using DIV elements

Tags: css, html

At the moment I am working with a table layout to achieve the look I'd like, but I keep reading that that's not really the "proper" way to go about this.  So I am curious about the proper way, and how to implement it.  I realize that there are several similar questions around here, but I can't quite make them work for me.

Here is what I'd like to do.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+  <- body { width:100%; height:100%; }
| +-------------------------------------------+ |  <- #banner { width:100%; height:200px; }
| |  #banner, fixed height                    | |
| +---------+---------------------------------+ |  <- #col1 { width:20%; height:auto; float:left; }
| |  #col1  |  #col2                          | |     #col2 { width:80%; height:auto; float:right; }
| |         |                                 | |
| |         |                                 | |
| |         |                                 | |
| |         |                                 | |
| +---------+---------------------------------+ |  <- #quick { width:100%; height:auto??; float:left; clear:both; }
| |  #quick links, height defined by content  | | 
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

The `#banner` contains an image, and has a fixed height, but width adjust to the browser window width.  The bottom div `#quick` too has the width of the browser window, but its height should be defined by its content (a collection of `ul` elements containing quick links, a site map if you will).

The two columns `#col1` and `#col2` have fixed widths (in percentage of the total width of the browser window).  Their height should be as follows:

- If empty or very little content, both/either one should stretch to fill the window so that the `#quick` div aligns with the bottom of the browser window.
- If much content, both should align with `#quick` at the bottom and nicely wrap their respective content and the browser windows scrolls as usual.  (One could still be empty, but its height is then defined/aligned with the other.)

The thing that I can't quite figure out is how to make the `#col1` and `#col2` divs stretch correctly to implement the above two points.

**EDIT** Playing around with the suggestions I realize that it's not so important to have `#col1` and `#col2` be the same size.  What is more important (and the `<table>` layout did work for that) is that if there is no/little content in those columns, then they stretch so that the `#quick` links stick to the bottom of the browser window.  (I tried to set `bottom=0;` for `#quick` but that didn't work.)

**EDIT** While both answers below seem working solutions to the problem, I wanted to avoid Javascript and too much fuzz over this.  What I ended up doing is adding a `div#col2 { minheight=100%; }` which stretches the div to the size of the browser window, and pushes the div#quick down.  Most pages have a good amount of content anyway, so that works well; for empty pages there's just some room at the bottom and that works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `fiddle` below

http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/7/

Updated Fiddle to make sure two columns are of same height

http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/14/

I hope this is it, haha

Comment: @Jens, Please see if this answers your question

Comment: Not quite.  I've added some colors, and you can see how the two columns don't stretch and align: http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/8/

Comment: @Jens, Please see updated fiddle, I added some javascript to detect browser resize, good question

Comment: Not sure if this is a jsfiddle problem, but the `#container` doesn't stretch to the bottom; of the iframe (browser window).  See the first of the bullet points above :-)

Comment: @Jens I think this will be it

Comment: @Jens I restructured JS a bit. :)

Comment: Hmm.. let me tinker with this.. I feel a bit hesitant to JS'ify too much.

Comment: @Jens,If you find a solution and if you don't mind, could you please share it with me. I am just curious to see an alternative. Thanks again :)

Comment: Matter of fact, as I'm poking around the internet I came across this site: http://www.layzilla.com/  There I could "build" my div layout, stickiness and all, and then look at the generated HTML/CSS code.  When I settle on something, I'll post it here!

Comment: I have a similar site with not tabular data just simple HTML layout using DIV's: http://blended-html.com

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for #col1 and #col2 to have the same height without using JavaScript.

However, you can make it appear that they are the same height by using a background image in a container wrapping the columns:

```
<style type="text/css">
.header {height:100px; width:100%;}
.container {background:url('background_image_with_left_column.png') repeat-y left top;}
.leftColumn {float:left; min-height:300px; width:20%;}
.rightColumn {float:right; min-height:500px; width:80%;}
.footer {clear:both; float:left; width:100%;}
</style>

<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn">Left Column</div>
    <div class="rightColumn">Right Column</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Even though the columns are different height, with a vertically-repeating background image (1px height is enough) in the column container, they will appear the same height regardless of content in the columns.

If you are making a page layout, I also recommend using a CSS framework such as OO CSS, as they are generally cross-browser compatible.